# While refreshing Sandbox, Selective Sandbox Access feature is missing

Tags: apex, lightning, sandbox-refresh, release

As part of Winter'24 release, Selective Sandbox Access feature was introduced. But I don't see this option to select Public group while refreshing or creating Sandboxes! Was it removed by any chance or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today the release of this feature is delayed due to an internal issue.

See the known issue page for [W-13748008](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000x9ZiUAAU/release-of-selective-sandbox-access-delayed).

Comment: Thank you very much! Somehow I couldn't find that link and spent lot of time figuring it out!